# iOS setSelectedImageTintColor uicolor not accepted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Following method is accepted if I set UIColor like:

```
[tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

However I would like to call it like:

```
[tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:colors];
```

when

```
- (UIColor *)colors{

    UIColor *colorIcon = [UIColor greenColor];

    return colorIcon;

}
```

and program returns an error "undeclared identifier colors". What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `colors` is a method, you typically need to write : `[myObject colors]` instead of simply `colors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[self colors]];
```